# What is the best practice or framework for making slides using html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, presentation

I have seen some cool slides in html, but some are CPU-consuming or browser-dependent. 
Since I am not very familiar with html5, I'd like to know what's the best practice or existing framework of making html slides.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And here is a more creative one similar to Prezi: http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js

Comment: I saw that, not very smooth on my laptop

Comment: Awesome link mate...that's a very very nice work....but it has some load on the browser

Comment: It's still raw but I think that with few optimizations it could become a reliable library.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an excellent little "framework" for making HTML slide presentations, with animations, transitions and such.

Link: [deck.js](http://imakewebthings.github.com/deck.js/)

I love it!

Comment: i liked your too and on performance level, it stands good....BTW you must check the link by @Ghigo .. It's great too.....

Comment: Checked, looks nice. But it's heavier :-)

Comment: ya that's the problem, otherwise a nice work....

Answer (score 2):

There is a great list of such presentation templates:
https://github.com/geraldb/slideshow/wiki/More-Slideshow-Projects-in-JavaScript

I found deck.js to be the best compromise between:

- simplicity: you write the html and launch it in your browser, no need for a web server
- customization possibilities thanks to the themes and clean structure letting you create your own CSS style easily
- functionality with the extensions
- possibility to print usable handouts

[Keydown](https://github.com/infews/keydown) is a good alternative which uses deck.js and markdown language to write the slides but requires ruby to create the html.

Answer (score 1):

The two options, I can recommend are following

- [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) : You can hard code the images and links
- [Agile Carousel](http://www.agilecarousel.com/) : Have the option to set it against some server script for rendering output

Answer (score 1):

Use this library to make interactive presentations, stories or ads.

[BoardJS](http://board.porizm.com)